# Angular2/4 - Cannot read property subscribe of undefined

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and recently start to learn it by reading a book 'ng-book The Complete Book on Angular 4'. In the 'how angular works' chapter I wrote a small inventory app followed by the instructions on the book but having issue after startup, shown as below:
[error log on browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uVzC.jpg)

All my components seem alright and the errors are just not seem relevant to my code. I even compared to the example code downloaded and they look very identical.

I know it's probably not that much of a big deal and I should move on and go back to this when I gain more knowledge. But really it's bothering me...

Not sure what's the best way of showing all my source code here so I created a shareable google drive link and a .zip with everything in that project can be retrieved by the link. ANY HELP WILL BE HIGHLY APPRECIATED!!!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B76fFkACV6wRdmtJU0Jfc0J4U1U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: By the way, the project was created by angular cli. And a smaller .zip with only src can be accessed by https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B76fFkACV6wRbkY2M1p5NHRnUW8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: pro tip: to showcase full code you could use github, specially if your projects are open source :)

Comment: In which component is the error triggered?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In ProductsListComponent, you need to change :

```
@Output() onProductSelected: EventEmitter<Product>;
```

to :

```
@Output() onProductSelected = new EventEmitter<Product>();
```

Also, remove the line in ngOnInit in the same component.

The event emitter needs to be initialized when the class is created. See this example : http://learnangular2.com/outputs/

Comment: Spot on! Thank you so much